# Reading a local binary file in javascript and converting to base64

Tags: javascript, base64

I have a *local* site which uses Javascript to browse files on my machine. This is not a NodeJS question. I have been reading *binary* files on my local filesystem and converting them to base64. The problem I'm having is when there are non-printable characters. The output I get from javascript is different to the `base64` command line tool in Linux.

An example file, which we can use for this question, was generated with `head -c 8 /dev/random > random` -- it's just some binary nonsense written to a file. On this example it yielded the following:

```
$ base64 random
Tg8j3hAv/u4=
```

If you want to play along at home you can run this to generate the same file:

```
echo -n 'Tg8j3hAv/u4=' | base64 -d > random
```

However, when I try and read that file in Javascript and convert it to base64 I get a different result:

```
Tg8j77+9EC/vv73vv70=
```

It looks kind of similar, but with some other characters in there.

Here's how I got it:

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    let fileContents;
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                fileContents = rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
    return fileContents;
}
var fileContents = readTextFile("file:///Users/henrytk/tmp/stuff/random");
console.log(btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(fileContents))));

// I also tried
console.log(Base64.encode(fileContents));
// from http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript_base64.html#.YVW4WaDTW_w
// but I got the same result
```

How is this happening? Is it something to do with how I'm reading the file? I want to be able to read that file synchronously in a way which can be run *locally* - no NodeJS, no fancy third-party libraries, if possible.

Comment: Hi ! I didn't know javascript (in the browser ?) was allowed to access the local filesystem. Don't you face a `Not allowed to load local resource` error ? That's what I get.

Comment: Works fine for me @Philippe - just produces an odd looking base64 value.

Comment: @HenryTK this is very non-standard / dangerous behavior. What browser / operating system are you using? Please try this in Chromium or Firefox and see what results you get.

Comment: Hi @Michael G, I'm aware this is dangerous. This is not code I intend to publish or put online. It's more of an experiment. I'm using Chrome and Firefox and get the same results.

Comment: @HenryTK I used to do that kind of thing all the time, finally switched to NodeJS. I don't mean your code is dangerous, I mean your browser is behaving dangerously. Unfortunately, I can't replicate your results. It might be an operating-system-specific behavior?

Comment: Yeah, I open Chrome with `open index.html -a 'Google Chrome' --args --allow-file-access-from-files` -- it doesn't normally allow local file access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

`fileContents = rawFile.responseText`

This will read your file as a JavaScript string, and not all binary is valid JavaScript character code points.

I will recommend using fetch to get a blob, since that is the method I know  best:

```js
async function readTextFileAsBlob(file) {

    const response = await fetch( file );

    const blob = await response.blob();

    return blob;

}
```

Then, convert the blob to base64 using the browser's FileReader.
(Maybe that matches the Linux tool?)

```js
const blobToBase64DataURL = blob => new Promise( 
    
    resolvePromise => {

        const reader = new FileReader();
    
        reader.onload = () => resolvePromise( reader.result );
    
        reader.readAsDataURL( blob );

    }

);
```

In your example, you would use these functions like this:

```js
readTextFileAsBlob( "file:///Users/henrytk/tmp/stuff/random" ).then(

    async blob => {

        const base64URL = await blobToBase64DataURL( blob );

        console.log( base64URL );

    }

);
```

This will give you a URL like `data://...`. You'll need to split off the URL part, but if all goes well, the last bit should be the right base64 data. (Hopefully).

Comment: I couldn't actually get this to work, but you were right about the `responseType` being the problem. I've decided to set this to `blob` and use an asynchronous request. For some reason `fetch` errored for me (said there was no `blob()` method?).

Comment: Glad you got it working. No `blob()` method usually means I forgot await (wrote `val = fetch()` instead of `val = await fetch()`.